# Ajax Class not found

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'am using ajax to insert data in database but get the error message ' Class utilizador not found'.

Structure:

gestor 
-> Model -> Calendario.php, Colaborador.php, Utilizador.php
-> Controller -> adicionaEvento.php

Colaborador.php

```
 class Colaborador extends Utilizador{

  // code

}
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
       data: data,
       type: "post",
       url: "/gestor/Controller/adicionaEvento.php",
       success: function(data){
          alert("Data Save: " + data);
       }
});
```

Calendario.php

```
public static function    adicionaDataByColaborador($utilizador_id,$data,$dias_ferrias_disponiveis){

    require 'DBconfig.php';

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO calendario(utilizador_id,data) VALUES(?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $utilizador_id,$data);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Colaboradores SET dias_ferias_disponiveis=? WHERE utilizador_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $dias_ferrias_disponiveis,$utilizador_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $conn->close();

    return true; 

}
```

adicionaEvento.php

```
require '../Model/Colaborador.php';
require '../Model/Calendario.php';


$id= $_POST['id'];
$colaborador = Colaborador::getColaboradorById($id);


$utilizador_id = $colaborador->getUtilizadorId();
$data = $_POST['data']; 
$dias_ferias_disponiveis = $_POST['dias_disponiveis'];

Calendario::adicionaDataByColaborador($utilizador_id, $data,      $dias_ferias_disponiveis);
```

Comment: Please mention which frame are you using?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi <script src="/gestor/View/assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

Comment: This may not be a jquery issue. youu need to check it in your php code.

Comment: The php code seems to be correct

Comment: Ok you ajax request url is not correct.

Comment: You also need to add tag #php so any php developer will help you in this.

Comment: Solution: put  require '../Model/Utilizador.php'; right before require '../Model/Colaborador.php'; in the file adicionaEvento.php